# Google custom search - getElement at null - can't access to <gcse:...> element

Tags: javascript, search, prestashop

First of all, i'm really sorry for my English (it is really bad ...).
I have a big problem in my work. I want to execute a google custom search query on load in page (prestashop website). I tried everything (with google api or 1000 different forum/website) but I can't get it working!

This is my code:

```
<div id="div_google_search" class="div_google_search">
            <script>
                var InitCSE = function() {
                    //google.search.cse.element.render();

                        var str="";

                        str= "{$search_query}";
                        var componentConfig = {
                            div: 'google_search',
                            tag: 'search',
                            gname: 'google_search',
                            attributes: {
                                    queryParameterName: 'query',
                                    enableHistory: true,
                                    enableAutoComplete: true
                                }
                          };
                        google.search.cse.element.render( componentConfig );

                        var gsearch = google.search.cse.element.getElement('google_search');
                        //console.log(gsearch);
                        gsearch.execute(str);
                };
                window.__gcse = {
                  parsetags: 'explicit',
                  callback: function()
                   {
                       if( document.readyState == 'complete' )
                       {
                           InitCSE();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           google.setOnLoadCallback( function () { InitCSE(); }, true );
                       }
                   }
                };

                var loadElements = function(){
                    var cx = '123:456';
                      var gcse = document.createElement('script'); 
                      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                      gcse.async = true;
                      gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                      //console.log(gcse);
                      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
                      s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                };
              (function() {
                loadElements();


              })();
            </script>
            <gcse:search gname="google_search"></gcse:search>
        </div>
```

And the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of null

I know that the variable gsearch can't getElement "google_search" for some reason. I want to know why..

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Where are you initializing `google` because that error tells me that something isn't initialized and the processor has no clue what you're trying to get it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved problem!

I forget the div specified in var componentConfig :

```
var componentConfig = {
```

> div: 'google_search',

```
                        tag: 'search',
                        gname: 'google_search',
                        attributes: {
                                queryParameterName: 'query',
                                enableHistory: true,
                                enableAutoComplete: true
                            }
                      };
```

The result:

```
<div id="div_gsearch" class="div_gsearch">
    <div id="google_search"></div>
        <script>
            var InitCSE = function() {
                //google.search.cse.element.render();

                    var str="";

                    str= "{$search_query}";
                    var componentConfig = {
                        div: 'google_search',
                        tag: 'search',
                        gname: 'google_search',
                        attributes: {
                                queryParameterName: 'query',
                                enableHistory: true,
                                enableAutoComplete: true
                            }
                      };
                    google.search.cse.element.render( componentConfig );

                    var gsearch = google.search.cse.element.getElement('google_search');
                    //console.log(gsearch);
                    gsearch.execute(str);
            };
            window.__gcse = {
              parsetags: 'explicit',
              callback: function()
               {
                   if( document.readyState == 'complete' )
                   {
                       InitCSE();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       google.setOnLoadCallback( function () { InitCSE(); }, true );
                   }
               }
            };

            var loadElements = function(){
                var cx = '123:456';
                  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); 
                  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                  gcse.async = true;
                  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                  //console.log(gcse);
                  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
                  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
            };
          (function() {
            loadElements();


          })();
        </script>
        <gcse:search gname="google_search"></gcse:search>
    </div>
```